# How to root ZTE Zinger (Z667T) running Android 4.4.2?

Tags: rooting

I've tried looking around, but I can't figure out how to root my ZTE Zinger (Z667T) running Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

[Towelroot](https://towelroot.com/) is a good rooting app with no need of a computer.

[SuperOneClick](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/root-android-phone-superoneclick-2/) uses the computer but still reliable.

Can't 100% guarantee that it will work, but it has a possibility. Good luck rooting your phone!